# Java 8 use streams to distinct objects with duplicated field value

Tags: java, filter, java-8, java-stream

I have a list of objects. Each object has three fields: `id`, `secNumber` and `type`. `Type` is enum which can have values `'new'` or '`legacy'`. Sometimes it happens that there are objects in that list which have the same `secNumber` a but different type.

in such a situation, I need to remove the one with type 'legacy'. How to do it using Java 8 streams?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use `toMap` with something like this:

```
Collection<T> result = list.stream()
    .collect(toMap(T::getSecNumber, 
            Function.identity(), 
             (l, r) -> l.getType() == Type.LEGACY ? r : l))
    .values();
```

where `T` is the class that contains `secNumber`, `id` etc.

- The `keyMapper` (`T::getSecNumber`) extracts each `secNumber` from each object.
- The `valueMapper` (`Function.identity()`) extracts the objects we want as the map values i.e. the objects from the source them selves.
- The `mergeFunction` `(l, r) ->` is where we say " if two given objects have the same key i.e. `getSecNumber` then keep the one where their type is  'NEW' and discard the one with 'LEGACY'" and finally we call `values()` to accumulate the map values into a Collection.

**Edit:**

following @Tomer Aberbach's comment you may be looking for:

```
List<T> result = 
            list.stream()
                .collect(groupingBy(T::getSecNumber))
                .values()
                .stream()
                .flatMap(l -> l.stream().anyMatch(e -> e.getType() == Type.NEW) ?
                    l.stream().filter(e -> e.getType() != Type.LEGACY) :
                    l.stream())
                .collect(toList());
```

The first solution using `toMap` assumes there can't be multiple objects with the same `secNumber` and `type`.

Comment: Maybe it's because it assumes there can't be multiple objects with the same `secNumber` and type? So if you had two objects of type `NEW` with the same `secNumber` it would chuck one of them.

Comment: @TomerAberbach true, edited to accommodate your comment.

Comment: @Aomine, I think it's not quite there because if you have a bunch of objects of only type `Type.LEGACY` for a `secNumber` you chuck them all. Check out my answer to see what I mean.

Comment: @TomerAberbach Right I see, +1 and btw I'll leave both solutions just in case they may want the first approach I've illustrated.

Comment: Thanks guys for your answers. I've used that second approach as first one is returning error that l is of type Object which does not have getType() method.

Comment: I think this is very simple `Set<String> keys = new HashSet<>();
  List<T> result = list.stream()
    .peek(i -> keys.add(i.getType()+i.getSecNumber()))
    .filter(i -> i.getType() == Type.NEW || !keys.contains(Type.NEW+i.getSecNumber()))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());`

Answer (score 3):

Assume `objects` is a `List<ClassName>` which has been declared and initialized:

```
List<ClassName> filteredObjects = objects.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(ClassName::getSecNumber))
    .values().stream()
    .flatMap(os -> os.stream().anyMatch(o -> o.getType() == Type.NEW) ?
        os.stream().filter(o -> o.getType() != Type.LEGACY) :
        os.stream()
    ).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

I made the assumption that objects of type `Type.LEGACY` should only be filtered out if there exists another object of type `Type.NEW` which has the same `secNumber`. I also made the assumption that you could have multiple objects of the same `type` and `secNumber` and that those may need to be retained.

Note that the `collect(Collectors.groupingBy(ClassName::getSecNumber))` returns a map from whatever type `secNumber` is to `List<ClassName>` so calling `values()` on it returns a `Collection<List<ClassName>>` which represents a collection of the groupings of objects with the same `secNumber`.

The `flatMap` part takes each grouping by `secNumber`, checks if the grouping has at least one object of `Type.NEW`, and if so, filters out the objects of type `Type.LEGACY`, otherwise it just passes along the objects to be flattened into the final `List<ClassName>`. This is primarily so that if a grouping only has objects of type `Type.LEGACY` then they are not left out of the final collection.